# Flutter: How to stop showing mobile App when running the Web version in browser

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am building an application using Flutter in both the Mobile and Web platforms. I have a few different UI to show from Web to Mobile. In the Web version running on the chrome when I change the size of the browser, it shows the mobile app pages.

How to stop this, so that the Web version should not show the mobile version when the browser layout gets changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you check the size of the layout like:

```
if (layoutSize <= someValue) {
  switchToSmallerLayout();
}
```

You can try to do like this if you want to prevent switching on mobile devices

```
bool get _isMobile => Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid;

if (layoutSize <= someValue && !_isMobile) {
  switchToSmallerLayout();
}
```

This should solve your problem.